# How to make the details html element to behave on Safari the way it does on other browsers?

Tags: html, css, safari, cross-browser, html-tag-details

Take a look at the HTML code in this snippet:

```html
<div class="container">
  <details>
    <summary>In a hole in the ground there lived a hobbit.
      <input type="checkbox" id="read-check" />
      <label for="read-check">
        I've read this one
      </label>
    </summary>
    Not a nasty, dirty wet hole or a dry, bare sandy hole. It was a hobbit-hole and that means comfort.
  </details>
</div>
```

On Chrome and its derivatives, as well as Firefox (haven't checked Edge yet), this behaves the way I assumed it would -- clicking on the input label **only toggles the checkbox**. But on Safari, both desktop and mobile, while clicking on the checkbox itself does the same thing, clicking on the label **also toggles the details expansion**.

How can I (with CSS and HTML only, no JS) make a details view with a labeled checkbox behave consistently across browsers?

Comment: Update: Bug was fixed as of Safari 17.2.1 on macOS and iOS/iPadOS 17.2. Possibly part of issue 114677170 listed at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-17_2-release-notes